# Put an object into an array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am using ag-grid for an application and it only takes arrays to display the rows.  I have an object returned from the API. This call always only returns 1 object.  I want to convert the object into an array of length 1.
This is my code:

```
jobResult.paged().$promise.then(function (results) {
    //ag-grid needs the result to be in an array
    var arrayResult = [];
    angular.forEach(function(results){
        arrayResult.push(results);
    });
    $scope.jobResult = arrayResult;

    if ($scope.lastResultGridOptions.api) {                         
      $scope.lastResultGridOptions.api.setRowData($scope.jobResult);
                            $scope.lastResultGridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
}
..rest of function
```

the `results` object has the data from the API.  But the `.foreach` function does not push the object into the array.
What am I missing?

Comment: Can you tell us `results`'s schema?

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) is pretty clear on how to use `angular.forEach`. Perhaps it's time to read it?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **[`angular.foreach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)** is wrong,

The correct way is, and then you can take the key or value and push to the array,

```
 angular.forEach(results, function(value, key){
       //push key or value
       arrayResult.push(value);
   });
```

Comment: The object that I want at the first element of the array is `results`.  What are value and key coming from?

Comment: what do you have inside results? is it an array or a object?

Comment: I figured it out.  I need the value to push.  This worked.  Thanks for your help despite the basic question.

Comment: @GloriaSantin Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

For your explanation, wanting an array length 1 with the results as [0], why not just push the results into the array:

```
arrayResult.push(results)
```

If you are trying to create an array from the results then you would want to run the .forEach on the results:

```
results.forEach(function(res) { arrayResult.push(res); })
```